# Is it a common practice to compare HLDs with the source code?

Tags: design, comparison

We have recently completed the development of a large system (150,000 lines of code more or less) which was developed from an HLD. Our stakeholders want to take the HLD and compare it with the source code. Is this a common practise? What is the goal of the comparison?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, why don't you ask your stakeholders what their goal is?

Comment: It's not common, but I can't tell from this question whether they're internal stakeholders or external, and whether they already have a right to the source code or not.

Comment: By "HLD", do you mean "High Level Design"?  If so, what format is it in, how much detail is there, etc?

Comment: -1 and voting to delete. Question is unclear and no sign of effort to improve it.,

Comment: what a grumpy bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming HLD means a High Level Design document, the most likely goal is to confirm that the HLD is a valid over view of the actual project as built. If it is valid then:

1. It can be used as such
2. The time and effort that went into making the HLD hasn't been wasted, thus it might be worth making one again next time
3. The people who were told to develop from the HLD did what they were supposed to do

If the HLD is only partially valid a typical response is to update the HLD so that it's current. However, it also may show an issue with the code that needs to be corrected. In many living projects it's common for design documents to become out of sync with code since code is actually used far more frequently.